# Get a file pointer in bash and read lines arbitrarily

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, io

I have a bash script in which I need to read a file line by line. I know how the usual `while read line` works but my program can't fit nicely into the `while` loop. I have two files and need to compare them line by line (it's not `diff`: the condition is whether the line in one file starts with the line in another file) with some conditions. Currently I have a Java version of the program and it has three nested loops, the loops of the two files are intertwined, and I need to break nested loop (which I know how to do). So I want an elegant solution to do the following basic tasks in bash (the following code is my Java program):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)); // initialize a file pointer
reader.ready();                                                        // whether the pointer is at the end of the file (used in while and if conditions)
lineStr = reader.readLine();                                           // read next line
```

All solutions I found on the web use the canonical `while read line` structure but my program can't fit into it. So I want to manipulate the files with more control.

Answer (score 5):

To compare two files line by line in a loop you can simply do this:

```
while read -u 4 A && read -u 5 B; do
    <do something with $A and $B>
done 4< file1.txt 5< file2.txt
```

OR

```
for (( ;; )); do
    read -u 4 A || {
        <read error/eof; perhaps you can send a message here and/or break the loop with break>
    }
    read -u 5 B || {
        <do something similar>
    }
    <do something with $A and $B>
done 4< file1.txt 5< file2.txt
```

Comment: Can you tell me what are the `4` and `5`? Are they just arbitrary file variable names?

Comment: By default files are opened overriding stdin (fd 0) but you can specify custom fd's for it e.g. 4 and 5. `read`'s `-u` option specify what fd to read from. (fd = file descriptor)

Comment: @konsolebox very elegant answer. Those are going in my toolbox :p

Comment: Is there an advantage in writing the less portable form `for (( ;; )); do`  instead of `while true ; do`?

Comment: `for (( ))` has its own handler. `while true` or `while :` calls `true` or `:` first which returns `0`, parses `$?` and decides if the loop continues from it which I find slower or less efficient.

Comment: Optionally for *bash 4.1+ (2009-12-31)* one can say `-u $foo` where `$foo` is opened by `done {foo}< "the_file"` – this makes sure the file descriptor is available (unless `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` is exhausted, by which one *could* do extra error check, but by then one are in too much trouble already).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that reads files into arrays and process lines from each (make sure you are not exhausting memory on multi-gigabyte files):

```
#!/bin/bash

## test input
test -r "$1" && test -r "$2" || {
    printf "\n  %s error: file not readable, usage: %s <file1> <file2>\n\n", "${0//*\//}" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

## save/set internal field separator to break on newlines
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
let linecnt=0

## declare arrays to hold lines from each file and read files
declare -a f1
declare -a f2

f1=( `< "$1"` )
f2=( `< "$2"` )

lines_f1=${#f1[@]}
lines_f2=${#f2[@]}

## test number of lines in each, iterate over lesser of two
if test "$lines_f1" -eq "$lines_f1"; then
    lines=$lines_f1
else
    test "$lines_f1" -lt "$lines_f1" && lines=$lines_f1 || lines=$lines_f2
fi

## iterate over lines in each file doing something with them
for ((i = 0; i < $lines; i++)); do

    ## do something with the lines
    printf "f1 [%d] : %s\n" $i "${f1[$i]}"
    printf "f2 [%d] : %s\n\n" $i "${f2[$i]}"

done

IFS="$oldIFS"

exit 0
```

Comment: This looks wrong: ``f1=( `< "$1"` )`` -- that will read the **words** of the file into the array. To read **lines** into an array, you need a `while read` loop or the bash v4 command [`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile)

Comment: It is correct - note the `IFS=$'\n'` above. Look at `man bash` and search `IFS` (internal field separator). By setting to `$'\n'` you read the entire line -- up to the next newline. Give it a try on any 2 files. Say `cp ~/.bashrc bashrc.txt` then `bash cmpfiles.sh ~/.bashrc bashrc.txt`

Comment: Right, missed that. Would be helpful to assign IFS closer to where it's value is really used. Your style is somewhat non-idiomatic.

Comment: Yep, You could swap the declare -a statements above the IFS setting and that would do it.